# CONSULTA SQL HIVE

Tags: select, sql, hive

Estoy intentando obtener un resultado de este tipo con una consulta SQL en Hive:

```
Gender    Age        CTR
Male      (0, 12]    0.75 
Female    (0, 12]    0.74
Male      (12, 18]   0.22
Female    (12, 18]   0.22       
 ....
```

Las bases de datos que tengo son usuarios y clics.
Usuario tiene los campos  userID, gender y age. 
Clics tiene los campos clics, impresiones y userID.

Todos los valores son INT, siendo gender 1 si es hombre 2 si es mujer. En el caso de la edad son numeros del 1 al 6 que representan rangos de edades.
El valor CTR se calcula haciendo la division de clics/impresiones.

Lo que quiero es calcular la media del valor CTR, ordenado por sexos y rangos de edades.

La consulta que tengo es esta, pero no funciona bien:

```
select case(a.gender)
    when 1 then 'Male'
    when 2 then 'Female'
    else 'Unknown' end as gender,
case (a.age)
    WHEN 1 THEN '(0, 12]'
    WHEN 2 THEN '(12, 18]'
    WHEN 3 THEN '(18, 24]'
    WHEN 4 THEN '(24, 30]'
    WHEN 5 THEN '(30,  40]'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'greater than 40'
    else 'unknown' end as age,
    round(avg(c.click/c.impression),2) as CTR
from usuarios a 
join clics c on c.userid = a.userid
group by a.gender, a.age
order by age asc, gender asc;
```

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: ¿Por que no funciona bien?¿Te da un error?¿Trae información no esperada?